# KO JS w/ kendo, multi conditional visible

Tags: html, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I am trying to display my "Amount may not be less than 1." message if the user inputs data, and the data is less than 1.

```html
<div class="form-group" data-bind="validationElement: Amount">
    <label for="Amount" data-bind="attr: {'for':'Amount'+$index()}">Amount</label>
    <input id="Amount" class="form-control" maxlength="13" type="text" placeholder="Required" required
    data-bind="attr: {id:'Amount'+$index()}, value: Amount, kendoNumericTextBox: { value: Amount, format: 'c2', spinners: false, step: 1, min:1, max:10000000000 }" />
    <span data-bind="visible: Amount() > 10000000000" style="color:#a94442;">Amount may not be greater than 10000000000.</span>
    <span data-bind="visible: Amount() && Amount() < 1" style="color:#a94442;">Amount may not be less than 1.</span>
</div>
```

If I make it only `visible: Amount() < 1` then it will always display because I guess  a blank text box is considered less than one. If I change it to `visible: Amount()` then nothing will display until the user inputs data, as expected. I need both though because it needs to validate that the user input data, and that the data is less than 1. Any clue? For some reason it doesn't like my `&&` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Apparently it was just not triggering for zero, so I added `|| Amount() === 0` and it resolved the issue.